# SQL Select values where name NOT LIKE EXCEPT one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a select statement and filter out some Locations, I have store locations with names, i.e.

```
"Alpha"
"Beta"
"Gamma"
```

And I have Warehouse Locations whose names begin with Warehouse, i.e.

```
"Warehouse 1"
"Warehouse 2"
"Warehouse 3".
```

I am trying to have a select statement to filter out all the warehouses EXCEPT 'Warehouse 35', is this possible? Or the only way is to exclude warehouse by warehouse?

Current Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Locations where LocationName not like ('Warehouse%')
```

Comment: can u show the sample data and expected result

Comment: Sure my data contains Stores and Warehouses on the same Table, there are 50 Stores and 60 Warehouses.

I am using Visual Studio to create some reports for a customer, but he doesn't want the information of the 60 Warehouses on the reports, he just want to see the 50 Stores and 1 Warehouse, so I need to filter out the other 59 Warehouses. I am searching for a SELECT  that can exclude all the warehouses except one.

Comment: Okay that makes no sense at all! If your customer wants a report with only `Warehouse 35` and all the other stores that maybe tied to other warehouse locations. How are you going to exclude those warehouse locations and still bring the store names? That is practically impossible IMO!

Comment: the locationname column contain store names and warehouse name?

Comment: Yes the LocationName includes all Locations (Stores and Warehouses)

Comment: then both of the below answer should work for u if u dont want any other condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine alternate filters with OR, e.g. to select Warehouse 35 and everything that doesn't start with Warehouse:

```
SELECT *
FROM Locations
WHERE LocationName = 'Warehouse 35' OR LocationName NOT LIKE 'Warehouse%';
```

Or in programming is generally inclusive, i.e. A or B is true if A is true, B is true, or both are true.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to filter out all the warehouses but not the stores, and just keep the warehouse 35 with the stores. The excpected result should get me all the stores and the warehouse 35 results.

Comment: @YorchAMC If you really need some help, you will want to provide some sample data and table structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
    create table loc
    (locations varchar(20));
    
insert into loc values ('alpha')
insert into loc values('beta')
insert into loc values('gamma')
insert into loc values('warehouse 1')
insert into loc values('warehouse 2')
insert into loc values('warehouse 3')
insert into loc values('warehouse 35')
                    
    
    select *
    from loc
    where locations not like 'warehouse%'
          or locations = 'warehouse 35'
    
    
    o/p will be
    
locations
alpha
beta
gamma
warehouse 35
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ed67/4)

Is this you wanted?

Comment: @YorchAMC is this the result you are looking for?

Comment: How is this different than the answer one below from @reaanb?

Comment: @nepalirookie when i created the fiddle the above answer was only  upto `SELECT *
FROM Locations
WHERE LocationName = 'Warehouse 35'` later he edited acc to the OP comment i think..

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for though! He needs to provide some sample data, without that it's just like shooting arrows in the dark.

Comment: @nepalirookie yup u r correct thats why i asked for sample output in the question comment section